# WordPress Widget to display a Stack Overflow profile

Tags: app, wordpress

### What?

Background: A [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) widget is a re-usable and configurable set of code that renders something visually, into a WordPress blog. The blog administrator typically configures the set of widgets to display, and where they should be rendered, for example on the sidebar.

This is a WordPress widget that renders a representation of a person's Stack Overflow profile.

Example rendering:

[image]

The rendering on your blog will vary, depending on the WordPress theme you use.

### How?

This widget is implemented in PHP, and uses the Stack Exchange 2.0 API to retrieve information from Stack Overflow. The administrator configures the Stack Overflow, userid, and the request Key. Like this:

[image]

The widget does not use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), because it does not need to. The widget does not authenticate to Stack Overflow on behalf of the user. It does not display the Stack Overflow profile for the user viewing the WordPress blog; instead it displays a single well-known profile, as configured by the blog site administrator.

### Why?

Some personal websites may wish to advertise the Stack Overflow activity or prowess of the blog author. This widget lets a person do that.

### Who?

Contact the author via from [the download page on Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/stackoverflow-profile-widget).

### When?

Available right now. The first release is 2012-06-19.

### What else?

#### License

[GPLv3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_3)

#### Platform

WordPress

#### Download

[Directly from Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stackoverflow-profile-widget/), or from within WordPress blog's admin panel: search for "Stack Overflow Profile"

#### Code

You can find [all the code on Subversion](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/stackoverflow-profile-widget/).

Comment: Doesn't work on WordPress 4.7.2

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble. It's running on my WP 4.7.2 site just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems fine, but it only works with SO. Definitely needs the ability to work with any SE site.

Comment: yeap, I figured people could/would modify it or submit patches, to make it more general.

Comment: I wish. I have way too much stuff going on right now to take on yet another project :)

Comment: yep, I'm sort of in the same situation.  This is what you might call the "Minimum viable widget."